# Not receiving full packet when sending data from STM32 to Android via Bluetooth

Tags: android, c, bluetooth, stm32, spi

I am sending accelerometer data from STM32 microcontroller to a HC-06 Bluetooth module, and I have developed an Android app to receive the data.

On STM32, I make a 3 byte packet (uartBuffer) which has the following structure: [0] counter, [1] xdata, [2] ydata.
I then send this data via UART to the HC-06 module. 
    `HAL_UART_Transmit(&uartHand, uartBuffer, 3, 10);   // {uartHandle, data, dataSize, timeout}`

On Android, I have no problem connecting with the device, etc. However, when I receive the packet, it doesn't arrive together. It does always arrive eventually (in the correct order as well), but I might get a packet with only the 1st byte, then a packet with the last 2 bytes, and sometimes other combinations, as can be seen in the logcat picture below. The value which always increments by one (i.e. 20, 21, 22, etc..) is the 1st byte of the packet as sent by STM32.

[image: Android logcat]

I have tested this with different sampling rates between up to 100Hz, and with bigger packets (up to 5 bytes).. I never lose any bytes, but the packet arrangement is further divided at higher sampling rates and data sizes.

Here is the ConnectedThread class which does the reading of data in the run method.

```
`
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

    private final BluetoothSocket mmBTSocket;
    private final InputStream mInStream;
    private final OutputStream mOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket mSocket) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ConnectedThread: Starting");

        mmBTSocket = mSocket;
        InputStream mTempIn = null;
        OutputStream mTempOut = null;

        try {
            mTempIn = mmBTSocket.getInputStream();
            mTempOut = mmBTSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get I/O Stream", e);
        }
        mInStream = mTempIn;
        mOutStream = mTempOut;
    }


    public void run(){
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[3]
        int mBytes = 0; // bytes returned from read
        String mIncomingMessage = new String();
        mIncomingStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while (true) {
            try {
                mIncomingStringBuilder.setLength(0);
                mBytes = mInStream.read(mBuffer, 0, 3);
                for (int i=0; i<mBytes; i++) {
                    mIncomingMessage = String.valueOf(mBuffer[i]);
                    mIncomingStringBuilder.append(mIncomingMessage + ",");
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectedThread - InputStream: " + mIncomingStringBuilder);
                Intent incomingMessageIntent = new Intent("incomingMessage");
                incomingMessageIntent.putExtra("theMessage", mIncomingStringBuilder.toString());
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(incomingMessageIntent);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "error reading from inputStream, e);
                break;
            }
        }
}
`
```

So my questions are:

1) Why am I not receiving the full packets in the same structure as they are sent from the STM32? A commentor here mentions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231598/how-to-read-all-bytes-together-via-bluetooth) that:

> The bluetooth connection is stream based, not packet based. There is no guarantee or attempt to preserve packetization. So any number of writes can result in any number of reads, just the stream of bytes are guaranteed to be correct. If you need to detect packets, you need to provide your own packet structure to wrap your data.

Is this true? Can Bluetooth really not preserve the full packet structure? Can anyone verify this?

2) If this is true, then what is the best method to construct a package which is easy for Android to detect the start of and end? I assume I need a sync/start byte. How do I ensure this sync byte doesn't occur in my accelerometer data? Should I use 2 consecutive sync bytes? Is a checksum at the end of the packet enough to detect if the packet has errors?

3) Finally, is it good practice to only use connectedThread on Android to receive the byte, convert to string and send to main activity so that its free to receive the next as quickly as possible? Then in main activity, I would reconstruct the packet? Or would this be too much work for main activity too?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In addition, looking at the time stamps of the inputStream, there are tiny time delays between the arrival of the different bits of the packet. (in the region of 0.03 seconds.
So although my STM is sending the full packet out in a single command, Android is receiving the different bits of the packet with very small time delays.